# Cent OS USB wireless adapter recognized as ethernet

Tags: centos, wifi

I have a TP-LINK TN823N usb wireless network adapter, I want to use this adapter on my dell workstation which running centos 7.

I downloaded the driver from TP-LINK official site, and compiled and installed it.

the compile process finished with error firstly, and I changed the `CONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211` parameter to `n`, then compiled successfully. Driver file has been installed into `/lib/modules/3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8192eu.ko`, then I reboot with UEFI security mode turned off, the driver seems loaded by system, but the device is recognized as ethernet, I can't specify my wifi password to connect...

Any hint on this ? My workstation is off internet right now, but if anyone want more detail please comment, I will copy with my usb disk

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "is recognized as ethernet"? Does it show up as `eth0` (than it's a possible udev rules screwup). What does `ip link` show? What does `iw list` show?

Comment: Output of `lspci` and `lsusb`, please.

Comment: Please [edit_here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/335541/edit) by adding the content of your wifi configuration file under : `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-your_wifi-interface-here` and others information from the previous comments

Comment: thanks everybody, I have installed `wireless-tools` and `wpa_supplicant`, now I can connect to  wifi  after executing the wpa_supplicant command, but  on the centos GUI, the wireless adaper is still recognized as a ethernet device, but It does not matter.

Comment: Change the device name from `enp...` to `wlp...`